# How to show that that Dyadic rational are dense in R.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

I am studying basic topology so I came across a set named as set of Dyadic rationals. I want to know that how can I prove their density in R?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263128/how-can-we-show-that-the-dyadic-rationals-are-dense-in-mathbb-r

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let the set of dyadic rationals be 
$$A = \left\{ \frac{m}{2^n}: m\in\mathbb{Z}, n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}.$$

We want to show that $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R},$ that is, for every nonempty open interval $(a,b),$ there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$a <\frac{m}{2^n}<b.$$

(**Remark: The proof is very similar to showing set of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$**)

Since $(a,b)$ is nonempty, we have $b-a>0.$
Choose large $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$b-a>\frac{1}{2^n}$$
(This can be done due to the Archimedean Property).
Then 
$$2^nb-2^na>1.$$
Observe that the interval $(2^na,2^nb)$ has length more than $1.$
Therefore, it contains an integer $m,$ that is,
$$2^na<m<2^nb.$$
Therefore, 
$$a<\frac{m}{2^n}<b.$$
Hence, $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: You proved it nicely